# Android dynamic layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to dynamically set the layout. I get a question (String type) as shown below :
Enter any two colors -------- and ---------

So using this string I have to create the view. Here the '---------' must be an EditText and the rest of the string can be a TextView. The blanks, i.e, EditText must appear inline as it appears in the question string. I am new to Android any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use this class for creating your dynamic views.may be it will help you.

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout l1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView text1=new TextView(this);
        text1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text1.setText("Enter any two colors");
        EditText edt1=new EditText(this);
        edt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edt1.setHint("COLOR1");
        TextView text2=new TextView(this);
        text2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text2.setText("and");
        EditText edt2=new EditText(this);
        edt2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edt2.setHint("COLOR2");
        layout.addView(text1);
        layout.addView(edt1);
        layout.addView(text2);
        layout.addView(edt2);
        l1.addView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mayuri for posting the answer. But the only problem I am facing is if the question length is long like Please enter any two colors you like..It just gets trimmed rather than getting displayed in next line